# how to underline pagenumber in Grid view using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview

I have one grid view in my web application. I use the following code

```
<asp:GridView ID="dataGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="True" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" 
                        CellPadding="4" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="true" Font-Underline="False" 
                        ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Left" PageSize="10" RowStyle-Width="20" 
                        Width="421px">
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="true" 
                            ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
                            HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

I want when i executing that code which displays the pagenumber should be underlined in grid view. Can anyone able to help for that.
Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple, use `PagerStyle`

```
<PagerStyle Font-Underline="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to show how to use the PagerStyle tag in context:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagerstyle.aspx

Here's information on what all the style properties you can use for PagerStyle.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tableitemstyle.aspx

I recommend you use the CssClass property to set the font to be underlined using css like

```
<PagerStyle CssClass="PagerControl">

.PagerControl { 
    text-decoration: underline; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the current page is under a span tag `<span>1</span>` you could do something like this:

On your CSS, add a class that extends to `span` element, add this to your class `text-decoration:underline !important;` (!important is so that it's not overridden) and then call that CSS class on your GridView's PagerStyle

Example:

CSS class:

```
.gvPager span {
    text-decoration:underline !important;
}
```

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server">

            <PagerStyle CssClass ="gvPager" />

 </asp:GridView>
```